# Push уведомления через Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, push-уведомления

Почему то, приложение перестало получать пуши. Отправляю через консоль Firebase, уведомления изначально приходили, но без звука и не отображались на экране, были видны только в общем списке уведомлений.

AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <activity
        android:name=".DialogActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".ResponseActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".DialogActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

MyService

```
public class MyService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DialogActivity.class); // года приходили уведомления, при клике все равно открывалоль MainActivity
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =

            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo)
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri) 
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =

            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

}

Вообще не понятно, когда срабатывает данный сервис, что бы он оправил данные на сервер ни разу не приходил токен.
Мне необходимо в коде получить токен устройства, я это делаю при отправке данных на сервер вызывая FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken().
Все работало, я получал токен, сейчас это у меня вызывает ошибку

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process ru.test.app. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(SourceFile:218)
    at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
```

При первоначальном вызове FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context), у меня все равно вылетает

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getToken()' on a null object reference
```

Как получить токен устройства, что бы оправлять на это устройство уведомление?

MyFirebaseInstanceIDService

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d("ddd", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String refreshedToken) {
      // код обновления токена на сервере
    }}
```

Вот такой код, но не работает, уведомления не получаю, отправляя их с консоли.
Подскажите пожалуйста, где искать проблему!

Answer (score 0):

Ваши симптомы такие:

- если вы не вызываете   FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) в Application.onCreate - сделайте это
- Добавьте проверку при получении getInstance - если он вернул Null, скорее всего он не проинициализировался, у вас проблема с конфигурацией. Прогоните еще раз wizard из Android Studio

По опыту получение токена работает неплохо так:

- Если при старте вам сразу отдали закэшированный токен - сохраните его, и в зависимости от вашего статуса логина отправьте его (обычно токен привязывают к пользователю)
- Если токен не отдали (Null) скорее всего он еще не получен, и ждете его через ваш сервис
- На сервере не забывайте чистить тот же самый токен у других пользователей (много глюков бывает из-за того что одно и то же устройстве выдает один и тот же токен после переустановок приложения)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Как понимаю, токен еще время от времени обновляется методом onTokenRefresh? его надо перезаписать у пользователя и возможны совпадение нового токена, с токенами которые уже есть, поэтому чистку делать надо?

Comment: Совпадения как правило бывают когда заходят с одного устройства разные пользователи, так как выдается один токен. Обновления, да бывают - но как правило один и тот же. Вообще чтобы не хранить токен лучше например подписываться на канал, который соответствует id пользователя в бэкенде - лучше какойто хэш, который не подобрать. Там другая засада - надо не забывать отписываться от старого :)